# Error "You must specify a valid lifecycle phase or a goal in the format" while executing jmeter test using Maven

Tags: maven, jmeter, jmeter-maven-plugin

POM file content am using to run jmeter file is given below but it is throwing error like "You must specify a valid lifecycle phase or a goal in the format" in command prompt.Please help on this

```
    <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.example</groupId>
  <artifactId>jmeter-maven</artifactId>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>jmeter-maven</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>com.lazerycode.jmeter</groupId>
        <artifactId>jmeter-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.1</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>jmeter-tests</id>
            <phase>verify</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>jmeter</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <jMeterProcessJVMSettings>
                  <xms>1024</xms>
                  <xms>1024</xms>
                  <arguments>
                     <argument>-Xprof</argument>
                     <argument>-Xfuture</argument>
                  </arguments>
               </jMeterProcessJVMSettings>
               <propertiesUser>
                 <users>${users}</users>
             <rampUp>${rampUp}</rampUp>
                 <loop>${loopcount}</loop>
                 <url>${url}</url>
                 <suite>${suite}</suite>
               </propertiesUser>
               <testFilesIncluded>
                   <jMeterTestFile>testplans/Ecommersce.jmx</jMeterTestFile>
               </testFilesIncluded>
             </configuration>
           </execution>
         </executions>
        </plugin>
       </plugins>
      </build>

      <dependencies>
          <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.lazerycode.jmeter/jmeter-mavan-plugin -->
         <dependency>
              <groupId>com.lazerycode.jmeter</groupId>
              <artifactId>com.lazerycode.jmeter</artifactId>
              <version>2.1.0</version>
         </dependency>
      </dependencies>
   </project>
```

When I run Jmeter file using Maven POM it is throwing error like "You must specify a valid lifecycle phase or a goal in the format" in command prompt

Below error am getting on command window

```
  C:\Desktop\jmeter\frameworkmaven>mvn verify -Dusers=1 DrampUp=1 Dloopcount=1 Durl=www.testing.com -Dsuite=framework
                [INFO] Scanning for projects...
                    [WARNING]
                    [WARNING] Some problems were encountered while building the effective model for com.example:jmeter-maven:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT
                    [WARNING] The expression ${url} is deprecated. Please use ${project.url} instead.
                    [WARNING]
                    [WARNING] It is highly recommended to fix these problems because they threaten the stability of your build.
                    [WARNING]
                    [WARNING] For this reason, future Maven versions might no longer support building such malformed projects.
                    [WARNING]
                    [INFO]
                    [INFO] ----------------------< com.example:jmeter-maven >----------------------
                    [INFO] Building jmeter-maven 1.0-SNAPSHOT
                    [INFO] --------------------------------[ jar ]---------------------------------
                    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
                    [INFO] BUILD FAILURE
                    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
                    [INFO] Total time: 0.192 s
                    [INFO] Finished at: 2018-11-01T21:16:26+05:30
                    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------


      [ERROR] Unknown lifecycle phase "DrampUp=1". You must specify a valid 

    lifecycle phase or a goal in the format <plugin-prefix>:<goal> or <plugin-group-id>:<plugin-artifact-id>[:<plugin-version>]:<goal>. Available lifecycle phases are: validate, initialize, generate-sources, process-sources, generate-resources, process-resources, compile, process-classes, generate-test-sources, process-test-sources, generate-test-resources, process-test-resources, test-compile, process-test-classes, test, prepare-package, package, pre-integration-test, integration-test, post-integration-test, verify, install, deploy, pre-clean, clean, post-clean, pre-site, site, post-site, site-deploy. -> [Help 1]

            [ERROR]
            [ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
            [ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
            [ERROR]
            [ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
            [ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/LifecyclePhaseNotFoundException
```

Kindly help on this

Comment: You forgot the minus sign before D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per Jens comment, your command line should be:

> mvn -Dusers=1 -DrampUp=1 -Dloopcount=1 -Durl=www.testing.com -Dsuite=framework clean verify

Also:

- you should use [version 2.8.0](https://github.com/jmeter-maven-plugin/jmeter-maven-plugin/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md) of [jmeter-maven-plugin](https://github.com/jmeter-maven-plugin/jmeter-maven-plugin)
- you should remove this block which is useless

  ```
  <dependencies>
       <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.lazerycode.jmeter/jmeter-mavan-plugin -->
      <dependency>
        <groupId>com.lazerycode.jmeter</groupId>
        <artifactId>com.lazerycode.jmeter</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.0</version>
        </dependency>
     </dependencies>
  ```